# Setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in Spring

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-storage

I'm attempting to use Spring to access files from Google Storage Buckets with the end goal of using MultiResourceItemReader to read in multiple XML files from the bucket.  I currently have Spring working with this process when the XML files are locally on my machine (not GCP)

Now, I want to do the same thing, but instead of XML files on my machine, the files are in a GCP Storage bucket. I can access the bucket contents outside of Spring, one file at at time.  For example this little bit of test code allows me to get access to the bucket and then see the files in the bucket.  In this snippet, I setup the credentials via the JSON key file.  (not an environment variable)

```
public static void storageDriver() throws IOException {
// Load credentials from JSON key file. If you can't set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
// environment variable, you can explicitly load the credentials file to construct the
// credentials.

    String name = "";
    String bucketName = "";
    String bucketFileName = "";
    String bucketFullPath = "";
    Resource myBucker;
    GoogleCredentials credentials;
    File credentialsPath = new File("mycreds.json");  
    try (FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath)) {
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
    }


    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
            .setCredentials(credentials)
            .setProjectId("myProject")
            .build()
            .getService();

    for (Bucket bucket:storage.list().iterateAll()){
        if(bucket.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("myGoogleBucket")){
            bucketName = bucket.getName();
            System.out.println(bucket);
            for (Blob blob : bucket.list().iterateAll()){
                bucketFileName = blob.getName();
                bucketFullPath = "gs://"+bucketName+"/"+bucketFileName;
                System.out.println(bucketFullPath);

            }
        }
    };
```

However, when I try to do the following with Spring,  Spring complains that I don't have the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` defined.  (which of course I don't since I'm doing it programmatically.

For example,  I'll add

```
@Value("gs://myGoogleBucket")
private Resource[] resources;
```

The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.

Comment: While using Intellij,  in the Run/Debug Configuratins,  I define the Environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and have it point to the json file that I'm doing via the code.   This gets be past the Spring runtime error IF I run this through the IDE..    Is there a different way to tell Spring what the credential json file is besides setting it via the environmental variable.   It also doesn't like it via the code I have previously shown.   This would be crucial informatin needing if I were to deploy this to a server and not running it locally.

Comment: to get more to the point. , how to access the bucket "list",  (the files within the Bucket) via Spring in order to use the MultiResourceItemReader?    In other words, how do I make Spring behave as if the google storage is like a directory on a computer.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud GCP simplifies your GCS configuration.

You can add [Storage support](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-starters/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage) to your app. Then, either specify the location of your service account credentials through the `spring.cloud.gcp.storage.credentials.location` property, or by [logging in with application default credentials using the Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login).

This will automatically provide you with a fully configured `Storage` object and things like `@Value(gs://YOUR-BUCKET/YOUR-FILE)` should just work.

Comment: This solves the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS issue by using the spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage dependency with the spring.cloud.gcp.storage.credentials.location property.   However, the main issue of accessing multiple files within the bucket still exists. eg `@Value("gs://myGoogleBucket/*.xml")`
`private Resource[] resources;`

Comment: It seems there are two questions in one. The only similar support spring-cloud-gcp offers for bulk file download from GCS are the [Spring Integration channel adapters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#_channel_adapters_for_google_cloud_storage). We don't offer support for cases like `@Value("gs://myGoogleBucket/*.xml")` right now.

Comment: The question was not how to use Spring to access a single file within a bucket,  but how to access multiple files with in a bucket in order to use the MultiResourceItemReader class.    Are you (Joao) saying that Spring does not support this when it comes to google storage?

Comment: Right now, the spring-cloud-gcp project doesn't support that kind of pattern resource resolution. Here is a [tracking issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/460), feel free to contribute there!

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways, but at last this excerpt from spring docs is the one which worked for me:

> Due to the way logging is set up, the GCP project ID and credentials defined in `application.properties` are ignored. Instead, you should set the `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` and `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variables to the project ID and credentials private key location, respectively. You can do this easily if you’re using the Google Cloud SDK, using the `gcloud config set project [YOUR_PROJECT_ID]` and `gcloud auth application-default login` commands, respectively.